# Ubuntu 16.04 with Radeon R7 250 freezes after suspend

Tags: suspend, amd-graphics

**Edit:** After couple of system updates in the last couple of months. The suspends problem is magically solved. Thanks everyone who provided suggestions.

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. However, whenever the system suspends or goes to screen saver, it freezes. I don't know if it's related to the ATI graphic card Radeon R7 250 and I have three screens connected to it. Is there any way to fix it?

```
$ lspci -v -s `lspci | awk '/VGA/{print $1}'`
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus LE [Radeon HD 8830M] (rev 87) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Venus LE [Radeon HD 8830M]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at f7e00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
Expansion ROM at f7e40000 [disabled] [size=128K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel driver in use: radeon
Kernel modules: radeon
```

Comment: This could be a bug in the radeon driver and so it's better to be reported to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bugs, without logs it is not possible to understand what goes wrong.

Comment: @AnthonyWong Thank you! Since the system just freeze I have to hard turn off the computer. After restart, there's no error message. Do you happen to know how to get logs?

Comment: I suggest you to use the `ubuntu-bug` command for reporting bugs. For log, kern.log should contain messages before you reboot, the `ubuntu-bug` command may also upload it to launchpad.net.

Answer (score 5):

Run `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub` and change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash'"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor acpi_osi='!Windows 2013' acpi_osi='!Windows 2012'"
```

Then,

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot twice!! This worked for me fine.

Comment: Can you explain what the heck is that? It actually worked for me! My laptop (Acer Aspire V, Ubuntu 16.04) was totally unresponsive after resuming suspending and now it works fine!

Comment: Wow! Worked for me, too, on an Acer notebook, Ubuntu 16.04). Would be nice to know what this actually does. Many thanks!

Comment: why reboot twice?

Comment: Yes, working fine. can you explain how it works?

Answer (score 4):

Installing `tlp` (Advanced Linux Power Management) can help to solve this problem:

```
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
sudo tlp start
```

I tried this on Linux Mint 18.1 64bit (Kernel 4.4.0-62-generic) on Lenovo s205.
More information about tlp:
[Advanced Linux Power Management](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-linux-advanced-power-management.html)

Comment: Make sure you take a look at the docs for more info. This was a great find thanks for the tip!

Comment: Okay I installed this. What settings should I adjust?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same card but I am running 14.04 and using the open source drivers. There is a bug in the driver which prevents the system from waking up after suspend operation.

I believe the bug just got carried forward to the new drivers.

Comment: Thank you! At least I'm not the only one. How did you solve it? Or did you just disable suspend and screen saver forever?

Comment: @EXP0 I couldn't. I don't suspend now. Tried a lot of methods but none worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
lino@linotu:~$ lspci -v -s `lspci | awk '/VGA/{print $1}'`
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 [GeForce GT 730] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GK208 [GeForce GT 730]
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Memory at fd000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=128M]
    Memory at f8000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at cc00 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

The way I found to avoid freezes or recover normally from suspend or after returning from screensaver mode and turning off the monitor, is to first turn the monitor on and then press a key or press the power to get out of suspend.

If I have the monitor on, waiting for signal, it recovers from suspend. If the monitor is off, it never recovers.

Strange, but it works.

Comment: If the question is about specific hardware, generally posting an answer about totally different hardware isn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can drive yourself crazy trying to "fix" the Dell/AMD suspend problem.  A simple workaround in Ubuntu 16.04 is to change your power and display settings to never suspend, change your time setting to show seconds, and run the power statistics program 24/7.  Perhaps not practical for everyone, but it works for me.  (PS I also run Ubuntu on a Intel Dell and have no post suspend issues!)