# Ubuntu 16.04 crashes when suspended on Surface

Tags: 16.04, surface

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 on Surface Pro 4. Now, when I try to suspend it or put the keyboard on the screen so that I suspend the session, Ubuntu crashes or something happens, but it doesn't work. I have to force shut down the Surface and restart it.

Can someone help me? I have tried a lot of things like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/770065/ubuntu-16-04-with-radeon-r7-250-freezes-after-suspend).

So please let me know what should I do.

Comment: Can you post `/var/log/syslog` to http://paste.ubuntu.com right after the crash happens please?

Comment: Hey, I've posted it.

http://paste.ubuntu.com/25276964/

Comment: Can you give me the link to your paste?

Comment: Hey, I attached the link. Did you get it?

Comment: Yes. I'll look through it and see if I can find anything

Comment: How much RAM do you have, and how large is your swap partition?  Your  swap partition needs to be as large, or larger, than your RAM size for suspend to disk to work.

Comment: Hi, the swap partition is about 2GB. But my RAM is about 8. SO what should I do now?

Comment: @SunnyDaze , I changed the size of my swap partition. But it still doesn't work. Can you help?